# Create a local database programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to create a wrapper class for creating a database.

I want the database to be created and destroyed in code by the use of create and delete functions.

I read online that using DROP DATABASE will destroy the database however I cannot check that I have interpreted the information correctly as I have been unable to write a create function.

The examples I have found are all for .mdf databases that include servers.

My database will be only used locally and will contain a single data table.

The database will be populated on creation by a data file chosen by the user.

Below is the class I have begun writing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace DatabaseForm
{
    class DatabaseManager
    {

        private SqlCeConnection _sqlConnection;
        private string _cacheDatabase;
        private string _password;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public DatabaseManager()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string ConnectionString()
        {
            return string.Format("DataSource=\"{0}\"; Password='{1}'", this._cacheDatabase, this._password);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private void Open()
        {
            if (_sqlConnection == null)
            {
                _sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection(this.ConnectionString());
            }

            if (_sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                _sqlConnection.Open();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private void Close()
        {
            if (_sqlConnection != null)
            {
                if (_sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    _sqlConnection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public void CreateDatabase(string dbname, string password)
        {
            string strCommand;
            try
            {
                Open();
                strCommand = "CREATE DATABASE " + dbname;
                SqlCeCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCeCommand(strCommand, _sqlConnection);
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Close();

                _cacheDatabase = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + dbname;
                _password = password;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in CreateDatabase(): " + exc.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public void Delete()
        {
            string strCommand;
            try
            {
                Open();
                strCommand = "DROP DATABASE MyTable";
                SqlCeCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCeCommand(strCommand, _sqlConnection);
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in Delete(): " + exc.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get this working before I worry about how the class could fail. I will add defensive code at a later date.

So the area of issue is to do with the SqlCeConnection. What does the connection string need to be in order to create a database?

Once the database has been created I can use:

```
_cacheDatabase = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + "\\MyDatabase.sdf";
_password = "";
string.Format("DataSource=\"{0}\"; Password='{1}'", _cacheDatabase, _password);
```

However MyDatabase.sdf does not exists until after CREATE DATABASE has been called.

Therefore what is the connection string?

Comment: Saying you are unable to create a database isn't enough. What issues do you have? Any errors/exceptions etc?

Comment: Do you definitely want a database?  Often it's better to just use files + keep stuff in memory if you dont need multi-user stuff

Comment: Was just about to say, it isn't entirely clear what you are asking. If you look through your question you will actually notice, that there is not actually a question present through the entirety of your text. Can you clarify what the problem with your class is?

Comment: What is the syntax required to create a database? The problem is with the CreateDatabase function. You can see from this there is no value in _sqlConnection. It complains about this value being blank. However I also think the actual strCommand value is incorrect. I am using a database because there are going to be upwards of 20000 records. The user will then need the ability to filter the records and only display those that are required. I could write classes to do this however a database provides all the filter logic for me.

Comment: @PeterLillevold - yeah I also found this page. However it is for a server database. My database will only run locally. It also has lines included about log on which I don't need. If I knew more about sql I might be able to interpret/modify the syntax but I don't yet, so I can't!

Comment: @Danaldo - ah, sorry, yes that link wasn't too helpful after all :) Deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with "DROP DATABASE". When using SQL Server CE, your database is one single file. It is enough to [delete the file](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/279552).

Comment: No reason other than consistency as sql is how I will probably create the database. That was the command I had read to delete a database via sql.

One strange thing does happen however if you just delete though... If you right click on solution explorer in visual studio and add a local database to the project it will prompt you for the type (dataset or entity). However if you delete that database, then add a second database the same way with the same name; it does not prompt you for database type...

Comment: Sure. Well, CE is special, so expect special behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to `DROP`/`CREATE` a database like that then the easiest way to get the scripts right would be to create a sample database in the SQL Management Studio then right click on the database and select `Tasks > Generate Scrips...`.

There are plenty of options to choose and among them also a `DROP`/`CREATE` one. Then all you need to care is how to execute the scripts.

Comment: This is a question about SQL Server Compact Edition. Databases will have to be created/dropped at runtime on the phone/device

Comment: It doesn't really matter. The `SQL` for creating the database would be the same (I guess) so why bother writing the scrips manually if you can create a sample database in the management studio and let it generate the scripts for you? I know it's about a Compact Edition. I just wanted to show an easier way for creating the scripts.